# Shared Libraries/Shared Projects in Visual Studio. What is the best way to implement in GitLab?

Tags: visual-studio, gitlab

I have considered using GitLab shared modules (one for each library) but that doesn't work because Visual Studio doesn't generate an assembly for each shared module.

If I create a separate repository for each shared project/library and include each project in the application solution then branching becomes a nightmare to manage.
It works but there must be a better way.

I have a .NET application in a Visual Studio solution which is a GitLab repository in itself. Also in that solution are three shared .NET library projects and each of them is a GitLab repository and each shared library project should create its own assembly. These shared library projects can be used by other .NET applications.

As I understand Visual Studio 2022 doesn't properly support multiple repositories in a solution.

So with that, if I want to branch the solution and its contents I have to branch 4 times: Once for the application and three times for the shared libraries. Which I think is error prone when switching between branches.

What would be nice is to branch once for the whole solution even though there are 4 repositories in a single solution.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question with the specific problem(s) you are facing? Can you give a minimal example of the repos/libraries you have, what you want to accomplish, and exactly what you mean by "nightmare to manage"

Answer (score 1):

> in Gitlab?

It seems to me the issue would be the same in GitHub/BitBucket/Gitea/...

> What would be nice is to branch once for the whole solution even though there are 4 repositories in a single solution.

That seems to suggest the use of a monorepo.

Note that [Visual Studio 2022 is supposed to support multi-repo](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/multi-repo-support-in-visual-studio/), but it is not quite there yet.

> ### Amend, Stash, Branch switching & Network operations
>
> Multi-repo support for Amend, Stash, Branch switching and network operations including Pull, Push, Fetch and Sync is coming to the Git Changes window in future iterations.
>
> [image: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2021/08/MultiRepo-GitRepo.png]

Comment: I have tried multi-repo in Visual Studio 2022 and seems to work satisfactorily.

Comment: @PaulGood Great! Does it handle branches correctly?

Comment: You still have to branch separately for each shared library repository. I think this is expected behaviour.